# Algolia analytics API cannot be called from frontend application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, algolia

Is it possible to call analytics API from javascript with jQuery?

I've been struggling with this for couple of days with no luck. I tried using CORS wich is sending OPTIONS request first which is rejected (405 error). Also tried with jsonp - but from what I read it has to be configured on server side?

Sample code (nothing fancy):

```
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://analytics.algolia.com/1/searches/test/popular',
    method: 'GET',
    beforeSend: (xhr) => {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Algolia-Application-Id', 'sample');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Algolia-API-Key', 'sample');
    },
    success: (response) => {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
```

Also tried with crossOrigin: true, and dataType: 'jsonp'.

Answer (score 1):

This API has not been designed to be called from the frontend (and therefore doesn't support CORS). You will need to build a proxy through your backend.

Comment: Yup just got the same reply from Algolia staff. Thank you :)